# passing multiple value from select element that has the same class to django views

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I have a problem to pass multiple value that has the same class in select element(because i use ajax to load the value of the option element)

example :

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="appendBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Column Name</label> 
                  <div class="col-md-4" id ="test">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">
                            <select class ="columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
                            {% for data2 in obj %}
                                  <option value="{{data2}}">{{data2}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}

                            </select>                
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="appendFilterBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Filter</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4" id="filtbox">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">

                            <select class="columnselect" style="width:125px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">              
                            {% for data2 in obj %}
                                  <option value="{{data2}}">{{data2}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </select>   
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

How can i pass all this value that has the same class? because i want to pass 2 value to the views django , and want to print it in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# you need to specify names of the field to get the value in the views and if you want to get multiple values for the same select tag, you need to apply multiple attribute of html

# html file

<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="appendBox()">Add</button>
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Column Name</label> 
<div class="col-md-4" id ="test">
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
<div class="btn-group">
    <select name="first-field" class="columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;" multiple>              
    {% for data2 in obj %}
          <option value="{{data2}}">{{data2}}</option>
    {% endfor %}

    </select>                
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="appendFilterBox()">Add</button>
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Filter</label>
<div class="col-md-4" id="filtbox">
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
<div class="btn-group">

    <select  name="second-field" class="columnselect" style="width:125px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;" multiple>
    {% for data2 in obj %}
          <option value="{{data2}}">{{data2}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



# views.py

def functionname(request):

    # if multiple is applied on your select tag
    first_field = request.POST.getlist('first-field')

    # if multiple is not applied on your select tag
    first_field = request.POST.get('first-field')

    print(first_field)
```

Comment: hmm can we apply this without multiple? because the user want to add the select element dynimcally so i add a button to add new select element

Comment: Yes, you can add a new select element. Keep the name of select element same. So that you can get the values in views.py - using :-  first_field = request.POST.getlist('first-field')

Comment: so there will be 2 element with the name of first_field?

Comment: Yes, so that you can get it in views.py

Comment: Sure, You can ask. Thanks

Comment: so the return value of first_field is list type? how can we print all the value ? we must do loop or something?

Comment: You have to loop over the list which you are getting, so that you can print the value.